# R- Interpreting named num output of predict

Tags: r, predict

I am using a linear regression model to predict.

```
 #t1 has 200000 rows, t2 has 50000,both have same columns
>reg<-lm(val~DER_mass_MMC+DER_mass_transverse_met_lep,t1)
>kk<-predict(reg,t2)
```

Output is a named num of size 50000. However it also has names for each element which seem to be arbitrary (in increasing order though)

```
 >head(kk)
   1           4           8          10          15          18 
 0.35498720  0.23365060  0.52591340  0.20095918 -0.01489389  0.35662207 
 >str(kk)
 Named num [1:50000] 0.355 0.2337 0.5259 0.201 -0.0149 ...
-  attr(*, "names")= chr [1:50000] "1" "4" "8" "10" ...
 > max(names(kk))
 [1] "99992"
> min(names(kk))
[1] "1"
> length(unique(names(kk)))
[1] 50000
```

What do these numbers mean ? I read the manual page of predict.lm but it doesnt seem to comment on it. Looking at the prediction outputs posted by others on the net, it seems that they should just be indexing integers 1 2 3 4 .. . Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me these appear to be row indices or something similar that stems from the structur of your `t2` object. I made a small example to visualize this.

```
t0 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(1,4,2,NA,NA))
t1 <- t0[!is.na(t0$b),]
t2 <- t0[is.na(t0$b),]

reg <- lm(b~a, data=t0)

> predict(reg, t2)
       4        5
3.333333 3.833333

> rownames(t2)
[1] "4" "5"
```

Does this seem plausible considering the structure of your data?

Comment: You are right. I had done something similar to create t1 and t2.
     > table(rownames(t2)==names(kk))
     TRUE 
     50000
confirms your hypothesis. Thank you !